# TFS Builder Server missing config file

Tags: msbuild, transform, app-config

I have a project that builds without errors on our build server (2012).  The issue is we are not getting the transformed app.config.

Using transform preview I see that the transform works correctly.  In the .csproj file, I see that the app.config and all of the transforms are added and transform on build are set to true.

```
  <ItemGroup>
<None Include="App.config">
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</None>
<None Include="App.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
</None>
<None Include="App.DEV1.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
</None>
<None Include="App.PROD.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
</None>
<None Include="App.QA1.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
</None>
<None Include="App.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
</None>
<None Include="App.UAT1.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
</None>
```

Other projects in the build have the correct config files.  Here is a relevant section of the build log.

```
10:53:46.166    66>Target "_CopyAppConfigFile: (TargetId:2226)" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\1_91\Sources\Path1\Path2\Path3\projname.csproj" (target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
                   Building target "_CopyAppConfigFile" completely.
                   Output file "D:\1_91\Binaries\Path3\projname.exe.config" does not exist.
                   Task "Copy" (TaskId:1543)
                     Copying file from "App.config" to "D:\1_91\Binaries\Path3\projname.exe.config". (TaskId:1543)
                   Done executing task "Copy". (TaskId:1543)
```

It does not find the transformed config and so it replaces it with the default config.  What could I try to fix this issue?

Comment: I was using Slow Cheetah which has worked for everything up until now.  So I installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform and that added the transform instructions to the project.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I installed [Configuration Transformation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform) and it installed the transform instructions to the csproj file.